# Template Laravel Ajuda!

Tags: laravel

Tenho dois arquivos blade.php e não estou conseguindo visualizar no browser o conteúdo.

```
@extends('layouts.index')

   @section('content')
   @parent
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Your Blog 2016</p>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    @stop

<footer>
      @yield('content')
</footer>
```

Comment: Não é assim. Seu arquivo template deve ser separado do arquivo content. 

No content que você chama o extends templates.

Comment: Coloquei assim so para mostrar questão yield e extends

Answer (score 1):

### master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    </head>
    <body>

        @yield('content')

    </body>
</html>
```

### conteudo.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h1>Teste de Template</h1>   
@stop
```

Precisa ter um Controller e uma Rota.

Já deve ter um Controller de modelo, use-o.

### SeuController.php

```
public function getIndex(){ 
   return view('frontend.pagina');
}
```

Arquivo **routes.php**

```
Route::controller("/", "SeuController");
```

Acesse:

> http://localhost/seu_site/public

Comment: Aqui ainda não deu certo. Estou começando laravel, tenho que criar um Controller ou não precisa ?

Comment: Não sei o que é isso não. Não deu certo.

Comment: Você sabe programar em PHP Puro ou OO ?

Comment: Sim, tenho experiencia.

Comment: Mas você disse que não sabe o que é. Não sabe o que é Controller, Rota ? O que você não sabe ?

Comment: Não sei o pq esta acontecendo isso tendeu.